# can two of the same lines of code be together in a string?

Tags: java

my job is to remove pay to play members privileges and make it all f2p.
so in some skills they have a multiplyer

```
if (owner.isSub()) {
  amount *= Config.RUNECRAFTING_AMOUNT_MULTIPLIER * 2;  
} else {
  amount *= Config.RUNECRAFTING_AMOUNT_MULTIPLIER;
}
```

so can i just remove the * 2 and be on my way or do i have to just change the whole thing?

Comment: I think you should try _something_, then test to see whether it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove "*2", why not replace all text just with

```
amount *= Config.RUNECRAFTING_AMOUNT_MULTIPLIER;
```

The only difference is that original version may throw NullPointerException if owner is null.But this is hardly an alleged behavior